# FTDI FT_Prog keeps crashing

Tags: jtag, ftdi

Anyone here using FTDI's FT_Prog?

At first I wanted to re-program the E²PROM of my FT232H to use it as a JTAG device but if I click `Scan and Parse` the program crashes after a few seconds without any kind of error message (only `program stopped working` from windows).
Even if I disconnect the FT232H from my PC I get the same behaviour.

Did anyone here use the program? Did it work?

Comment: I do, to set the chips eeprom. Works for me

Comment: This happens to me too, though only on my Windows 8.1 laptop. I have a Surface Pro 3 running Windows 10 and FT_Prog works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try disconnecting all other USB devices then try again. One or more of your USB devices are incompatible with the `FT_Prog` utility causing it to crash. If you identify the incompatible device, leave it disconnected when using `FT_Prog`.

I had this problem. Every time my Atmel-ICE (AVR programmer) was connected `FT_Prog` would crash on `Scan and Parse`. The problem was solved by leaving the Atmel-ICE disconnected; and later by updating its firmware.